# Populate dataframe cell with a vector

Tags: r

Is it possible to populate a dataframe cell with a list?

This is my code:

```
input_vector <- sample(1:1000, 200)
input_vector

new_data_frame <- data.frame("Values" = numeric() , "Divisors" = numeric())
new_data_frame

for (i in input_vector) {
  if (i %% 3 == 0 & i %% 7 == 0) {
   new_data_frame[nrow(new_data_frame)+1, 1] <- i
   new_data_frame[nrow(new_data_frame), 2] <- c(3, 7)
  } 
  }

new_data_frame
```

However, it seems that I can't populate the second column with c(3,7). Running the code without this following line works:

```
new_data_frame[nrow(new_data_frame), 2] <- c(3, 7)
```

Also, when I add the numbers 3 and 7 as a string, it works. Why can I add strings to a SINGLE cell in a dataframe, but not vectors or lists.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to use is something called a *list-column*. In general, columns in frames are vectors, not lists, which has (among others) a couple simple properties: `[` always returns an atomic thing, and most operations that work on frames work on all of the columns. As soon as a column is a `list` instead of a `vector`, some things might work differently.

To demonstrate:

```r
mt <- head(mtcars)
### "set up" the third column as a list
mt[[3]] <- as.list(mt[[3]])

### while it "looks normal",
mt
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

### ... its output is obviously different
mt[,2]
# [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6
mt[,3]
# [[1]]
# [1] 160
# [[2]]
# [1] 160
# [[3]]
# [1] 108
# [[4]]
# [1] 258
# [[5]]
# [1] 360
# [[6]]
# [1] 225
```

From here, you can use the double-bracket notation:

```r
mt[[2,3]] <- c(3, 7)
mt
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 3, 7 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
mt[,3]
# [[1]]
# [1] 160
# [[2]]
# [1] 3 7
# [[3]]
# [1] 108
# [[4]]
# [1] 258
# [[5]]
# [1] 360
# [[6]]
# [1] 225
```

Some things that are "natural" with not-listified frames will start showing differences:

```r
sapply(mt, class)
#       mpg       cyl      disp        hp      drat        wt      qsec        vs        am      gear      carb 
# "numeric" "numeric"    "list" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" 

colSums(head(mtcars))
#     mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat      wt    qsec      vs      am    gear    carb 
#  123.00   36.00 1271.00  703.00   20.64   17.93  108.77    3.00    3.00   21.00   13.00 

colSums(mt)
# Error in colSums(mt) : 'x' must be numeric
sapply(mt, function(a) sum(unlist(a)))
#     mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat      wt    qsec      vs      am    gear    carb 
#  123.00   36.00 1121.00  703.00   20.64   17.93  108.77    3.00    3.00   21.00   13.00
```

and many others exist.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, but is not recommended. Each column of a df has to have the same class, so if you change the class of `df` from numeric to list, you can then put whatever you like in it, although it might not behave as expected! (as explained by @r2evans above)